# Starting on gesture events handling

Tags: android, slideshow, android-imageview, gestures

I have been new to android. I have just gone through my slideshow app.

I want to make image slide using touch event just like facebook app. when we click on image and swipe it to left then new image shown and when swipe finger towards right then last old image is shown.

I don't know how this works and how to start with it. Can any one help me in this case to start with like providing tutorials and tips ?

I just want effect on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling simple touch events works the following:

1. You need an OnTouchListener in your Activity. Add it by implementing the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) interface.
2. You will have to override the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) method. This will be called if a touch gesture is recognized.
3. Now you get all the information about the Touch (in Android it is called MotionEvent) in the onTouch Method via the MotionEvent. Look at the [MotionEvent-Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) documentation to use the correct methods to handle your swipe gesture.
4. You could first ask what action really happened. Call getAction(). It will return the type of action. The easiest way would be to react to ACTION_MOVE.
5. Then ask for the origin of the touch event and the later position of the touch by using getHistoricalX(int)/getHistoricalY(int) and getX(int) and getY(int) (attention: these methods are only usable for ACTION_MOVE events - in your case it is ok).
6. Now as you have the start and end coords of the swipe gesture, you can calculate the length of the swipe in pixels and the direction of the swipe and that is all what you need.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's two bits of information that you might want. The first thing is, what you are referring to is called a gallery. There's several great examples of how to use a gallery, the basic idea is you get a BaseAdapter Class that gets the view and attach it to the gallery. See [this tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example/) for an example, or just google Android Gallery Example, you'll find alot of examples.

The second is gesture programming. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747) for more information

Comment: I dont want to show gallery with list of images. Im showing one image on screen and want effect of thumb scroll from left to right and right to left. Right now i have next and previous buttons. It works with that..

Comment: Okay, added a second link that you might find interesting on the subject.